# angular, map: map give result to subscribe late

Tags: angular7

I want to build a user page with `Angular`.

In my service I am getting data by this code.

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/getUser.php?id=${id}`).pipe(
        map((res) => {
            this.user = res['data'];
            return this.user;
       }),
       catchError(UsersService.handleError));

}
```

In component I am saving data into variable user. This is code.

```
  user: User;

  constructor(
      private UsersSer: UsersService,
      private ActiveRout: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getUser();
  }

  getUser() {
      const id = +this.ActiveRout.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

      this.UsersSer.getUser(id).subscribe(user => {
          this.user = user;
          console.log(this.user);
      }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
      });
```

}

And printing in html.

```
<div class="main-box clearfix">
    <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>

    <div class="profile-status">
         <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> {{user.status}}
    </div>

    <img src="../../assets/images/{{user.image}}" alt="" class="profile-img img-responsive center-block">

    <div class="profile-label">
        <span class="label label-danger">{{user.role}}</span>
    </div>


</div>
```

When i run code in browser i see that data comes too late.

[image: browser screen]

I am new in stack overflow sorry if i do mistake.

Errors screenshot.

[image: errors screen]

Comment: Can you display the screenshot showing the error separately - it's not clear what it's showing

Comment: I was added screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an ngif testing that user isn't undefined so you're not binding to it before it's loaded:

```
 <div class="main-box clearfix">
    <div *ngIf="user != undefined">
       <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>

        <div class="profile-status">
         <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> {{user.status}}
       </div>

    <img src="../../assets/images/{{user.image}}" alt="" class="profile-img img-responsive center-block">

       <div class="profile-label">
        <span class="label label-danger">{{user.role}}</span>
    </div>

   </div>
</div>
```