# Async calls in angular, promises or observables

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, observable

I understand that this is a very common topic, but i'm stuck and i can't understand all the solution.

I have an Angular 6 application which calls an API in Java Spring to query the database.

My problem is, for exemple on one page i have to query the database several time in on component.

nbOnInit() execute getGames(), getTasks(), and getGlobalProgress().

The first problem is that getGames() is late, and in the chrome console i have several issues, for exemple "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" (which is a property of the Game type), and when Games[] is finally resolved, it displays as it should. How can i suppress these errors ?

The second problem is that in getGlobalProgress() i need this.progress, which is affected in getTasks() earlier. But getTasks() is late again and this.globalProgress is never set...

I guess i need some sort of async calls, like promises or observable, i thought the ".subscribe" was enough but i was wrong. I found a lot of code example online but i can't figure out which one to use, or how to use it. I'd appreciate some help, thank you very much.

Here is the ts file of the concerned component :

```
export class SingleGameComponent implements OnInit {

private game: Game[];
private tasks: Task[];
private progress: Progress[];
private globalProgress: number;
private id: any; // Game id

constructor(private gameService: GameService, 
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private taskService: TaskService,
            private progressService: ProgressService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.getGames();
  this.getTasks();
  this.getGlobalProgress();
}

getGames(): void {
  this.gameService.getGameById(+this.id)
    .subscribe(game => this.game = game);
}

getTasks(): void{
  this.taskService.getTasksByGameId(+this.id)
    .subscribe(task => this.tasks = task);

  this.progressService.getProgressByUserAndGame(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id, +this.id)
  .subscribe(progress => this.progress = progress);
}

getGlobalProgress(): void{
  this.progressService.calculateGlobalProgress(this.progress)
  .subscribe(globalProgress => this.globalProgress = globalProgress);
}
```

}

Here is one method from a service (they are all the same) :

```
    getGameById(id: number){
  return this.httpClient.get<Game[]>(this.BASE_URL+'game/id/'+id);
}
```

Comment: you can use `Observable.zip` to solve this. Anyway it's up to you, but Observable is better than promise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'll look it up.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446194/angular-map-map-give-result-to-subscribe-late?noredirect=1#comment93765958_53446194 for an example of subscribing to a method returning an observable, and also how to avoid the "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined" errors.

Comment: *i need some sort of async calls, like promises or observable*: every time you call one of your service and subscribe to the observable it returns, you **are** doing an asynchronous call. It's asynchronous, which means that the ngOnInit method returns, and the component displays **before** you get the results. So you need to check, in the emplate, that the data is there before trying to display it. *ngIf is your friend.

Comment: Thank you ! i have resolved the undefined errors ! But i still got the problem of the getGlobalProgress(). I have to wait for this.progress to be set to launch getGlobalProgress(), how can i do it ?

Comment: Use the switchMap operator to call a service, then when you got the response, call the other one. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap

Comment: Ok thank you but i don't know why, i don't get it... i found this :
    
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = clicks.pipe(switchMap((ev) => interval(1000)));
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

But i don't know how to apply it to my situation ..